# 100% width w/o parent element

Tags: css, google-chrome, width, element, viewport

I'm a bit confused. I'm building an To-Do List app and I'm trying to set the header as 100% of the screen width. I have the correct meta tags, I believe, but setting the header at 100% width is stretching the element past the right side of the screen. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>

 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <title>Todo List App</title>

 <link rel="stylesheet" text="text/css" href="style.css">


 </head>
 <body>
     <header>

         <input type="text" placeholder="Enter an activity...">

         <button></button>

     </header>
 </body>
</html>

@charset "UTF-8";

header {
width: 100%;
height: 80px;
position: fixed;
padding: 15px;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
z-index: 5;
background: #25b99a;
box-shadow:0px 2px 4px rgba(44, 62, 80, 0.15);
border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}

header input {
width: 100%;
height: 50px;
float: left;
background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
border-top-left-radius: 5px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
border-top-right-radius: 25px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
border-radius: 5px;
border: 0px;
box-shadow: none;
outline: none;
}
```

Comment: Try adding `* { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box }` to your CSS.

Comment: float the header.

Comment: Floating a fixed header doesn't make sense....

Comment: ofc it does, every non absolute positioned element has to be floated unless you wanna work with bad practices and produce low quality stuff

Comment: @mheonyae The header is **fixed** so floating would have NO EFFECT.

Comment: @mheonyae https://jsfiddle.net/hbyLtsy2/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the `box-sizing` property.

[Info from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  position: fixed;
  padding: 15px;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 5;
  background: #25b99a;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(44, 62, 80, 0.15);
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}

header input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 25px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 0px;
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter an activity...">
  <button></button>
</header>
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly. Thanks for the link as well. It makes perfect sense.